# ValueError: Unknown pooler type

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

**when i tried to facebook research code with Colab, machine say me:**

> ValueError: Unknown pooler type

source code: `[https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QIoL2g0jdt5E-vYKCIojkIz21j3jyEvo?usp=sharing][1]`

The title I got error is here: Instance Segmentation Using PointRend

**How to fix this error?**

```
segmenter = get_pointrend_predictor()
instances = segmenter(image)["instances"]
vis = PointRendVisualizer(image, metadata=MetadataCatalog.get("coco_2017_val"))
Image.fromarray(vis.draw_instance_predictions(instances.to("cpu")).get_image())
```

> ValueError: Unknown pooler type

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOF8y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Also took me a day to figure out. I think it's due to Detectron2 compatibility,

Try install Detectron2 as following:

```
!mkdir -p external
!git clone --branch v0.2.1 https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git external/detectron2
!python -m pip install -e external/detectron2
```

see https://github.com/facebookresearch/phosa/issues/4